# Why do Nvidia mobile cards not work with Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, opengl

I've gone through 8 laptops already.  I keep returning them because I can't get Ubuntu working with the latest Nvidia drivers.  When I first install Ubuntu it works perfectly.  But I need OpenGL 4.3 so I need to install the latest Nvidia driver.  Once I do that and reboot Ubuntu crashes.  I have also tried this with Linux Mint and same results.  My current laptop is an Acer Aspire V 15 Nitro (VN7-571G-769P) with an Nvidia GeForce 840M.  I can't believe I can't get linux with OpenGL 4.3 working.

I'm getting the following error

```
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0"`
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you install?

Comment: I've tried 14.04, 14.10, 15.04 and they all fail.

Comment: You need to install `nvidia-346` and `nvidia-prime`

Comment: The short answer is: they do work with no problem.

Comment: "nvidia cards" i a broad topic, as with ATI or intel cards, some work well with linux and some do not. Those that do not are usually because the drivers are close source, so ask ATI,Intel, and Nvidia to open source their drivers and / or support Linux in parity with Windows or OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install drivers to Ubuntu 14.04 this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

In 15.04 just `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime`.

Comment: This worked.  This whole time I've been trying to just download the driver from the Nvidia site and install it manually.